# Select Text & highlight selection or get selection value (React)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, electron

I have a React application which displays some spans:

```
<span>Hello</span> <span>my</span> <span>name</span> <span> is </span> ...
```

I would like the user to select the text with the mouse like so [image: Hello my Name is]

..and then get the selected value, or highlight the text etc.
How would I do this in React? I am not sure what event handlers to use and how to get hold of the current selection! A minimal example or a hint would be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the Highlighted/Selected text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/get-the-highlighted-selected-text)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, as I am asking specifically about React here - but I guess there is no React specific solution then?

Comment: there is no need for specific react solution, as there is more powerful and general solution that works across all JS frameworks / approaches - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection

Comment: I understand. The only thing I'm saying is that this then does not make it a duplicate as my question aimed at React specifically. The answer then should be that there are not React specific handlers for this. But well, I guess I also was not clear enough in my question. Thanks a lot anyways.

Comment: now I got you. Right, sorry! I've edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Oh I also just edited yours! I hope I didn't overwrite anything!

Comment: I've taken yours, no worries, all good. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no React-specific solution for this. Just use [window.getSelection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection) API.

---

To output highlighted text run `window.getSelection().toString()`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: You just have to bind a "OnMouseUp" , then use the "getSelection" method presented here

Answer (score 24):

Use `onMouseUp` and `onDoubleClick` events to detect to call method, that will determine selection using JavaScript Selection API.

Use `window.getSelection()` to get selection object.

To get selected text, use `window.getSelection.toString()`.

To get coordinates of selected text area for rendering popup menu, use `selection.getRangeAt(0).getBoundingClientRect()`.

As an example implementation, take a look at [react-highlight](https://github.com/ydeshayes/react-highlight) library.

Comment: What if the user selects the text using Shift + arrows in the keyboard without interacting with mouse?

Comment: There is no such use case, because when browsing web pages you don't have keyboard controlled cursor for non editable areas.

Comment: @AntonAL I'm afraid you're wrong. Try it: double click on the word "JavaScript" in the answer above to select it and then press Shift+Cursor Right; you will see the selection expand without further mouse interaction.

Answer (score 10):

Here's an example in React using a functional component:

```
const Post = () => {
    const handleMouseUp() {
        console.log(`Selected text: ${window.getSelection().toString()}`);
    }
    return (
        <div onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}>Text</div>
    );
}
```

As Lyubomir pointed out the window.getSelection() API does the trick!

Comment: I just copy that as a function in my component ! It works perfectly just npx create react app and delete app.js and add this : let doit = () => {
  document.onmouseup = () => {
    console.log(window.getSelection().toString());
  };
};

Answer (score 6):

I think that it's the right way...

```
 document.onmouseup = () => {
   console.log(window.getSelection().toString());
 };
```

Comment: THIS IS THE SOLUTION ! thanks JuliSMz just add this function in your JSX if you are using react.js

Comment: Rap it under a function let doit = () => {
  document.onmouseup = () => {
    console.log(window.getSelection().toString());
  };
};

Answer (score 3):

Step 1: - Initially Mouse will capture **every time** you enter something

```
<textarea type="text" 
          className="contentarea__form__input" 
          onMouseUpCapture={this.selectedText}>
</textarea>
```

Step 2: To make sure it **only** catches your selected text I used if-else condition

```
selectedText = () => {
    window.getSelection().toString() ? console.log(window.getSelection().toString()) : null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Due to this [bug in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=85686), I was unable to get it working with
`window.getSelection()` as suggested by other answers.

So I had to do the following (in React):

```js
constructor(props) {
    this.textAreaRef = React.createRef();
}

getSelection() {
    const textArea = (this.textAreaRef.current as HTMLTextAreaElement);
    console.log(textArea.value.substring(
            textArea.selectionStart,
            textArea.selectionEnd
        )
    );
}

render() {
    <textarea onMouseUp={() => this.getSelection()}
                        ref={this.textAreaRef}>
    </textarea>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just made a custom hook for this (in typescript if needed):

```
    export const useSelectedText = () => {
        const [text, setText] = useState('')
        const select = () => {
            const selected = window.getSelection() as Selection
            setText(selected.toString())
        }
        return [select, text] as const
    }
```

Comment: How is select used in the code? On what event should it be called? onMouseCapture?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `react-text-annotate`
library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-text-annotate

Answer (score 0):

We can do using state simply to select and highlight them.

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const ClipBoardLink = styled.span<{ selection: boolean }>`
  background: ${(p) => (p.selection ? '#1597E5' : '')};
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
  color: ${(p) => (p.selection ? '#fff' : '')};
`;

const GroupOrderModel = () => {
  const [isCopied, setIsCopied] = useState(false);

  const handleIsClipboardCopy = async (text: string) => {
    setIsCopied(true);

    navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);

    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsCopied(false);
    }, 5000);
  };

  return (
      <ClipBoardLink selection={isCopied} onClick={async () => await handleIsClipboardCopy("Click me!")}>Click me!</ClipBoardLink>
   );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to grab the first and last indices, and figure out the words from there.

```
const [highlightStart, setHighlightStartIndex] = useState();
const [highlightEnd, setHighlightEnd] = useState();
const paragraph = "some text in paragraph blah blah blah";
const paragraphArr = paragraph.split(" ").map((word, index) => (
    <span
      key={index}
      id={`paragraph_${index}`}
      onMouseDown={(e) => handleHighlightStart(index)}
      onMouseUp={(e) => handleHighlightEnd(index)}
    >
      {word}{" "}
    </span>
  ));


const handleHighlightStart = (index) => {
    console.log("highlightStart", index);
    setHighlightIndexStart(index + 1); //because start word is the one after cursor starts
  };

  const handleHighlightEnd = (index) => {
    console.log("highlightEnd", index);
    setHighlightIndexEnd(index - 1); //because end word is the last one before cursor ends
  };
```

You can figure out the selected text from the indices. You would also need to take care of cases when the user highlights backward.