# How to prevent select event from firing after every input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, textbox, contenteditable

I'm trying to create a custom text editor in React, thus I've created a `div` which has a `contentEditable` attribute. Now I want to perform some action when the user selects a part of the inputted text. To do that I'm using the `select` event as `onSelect` attribute on my div. The problem is that, `select` event runs not only when selecting the text, but also when I click on the input box, or after any input. How can I prevent it, so that it gets fired only when the text is selected ?

Component:

```
function EditorBody(props) {
  return (
    <div className="editor-body">
      <div
        className="text-section"
        contentEditable
        role="textbox"
        placeholder="Text goes here ..."
        onSelect={() => window.alert("You've selected a text")} // Runs after every input, not only when the text is selected
      ></div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default EditorBody;
```

Comment: When you say "the user selects a part of the inputted text" do you mean to highlight the text, or just place the cursor somewhere near some specific text?

Comment: @silencedogood, yes, I mean highlighting it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select Text & highlight selection or get selection value (React)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43184603/select-text-highlight-selection-or-get-selection-value-react)

Comment: @silencedogood Not really, unfortunately. My problem is event being fired even after every input, when normally it shouldn't be.

Comment: Well... As that answer points out, I think using onMouseUp would be a more proper event here if your looking to select highlighted text. With this event, you can check if the selection is greater than zero. If it is, run your selection method. If not, do nothing.

Comment: @silencedogood thanks a lot. It's a nice solution !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the logic in your `onSelect` to be able to determine whether or not to execute the selected logic.

```
onSelect={(event) => {
  if (document.getSelection().toString().length > 0) {
     // your selection logic
     window.alert(document.getSelection().toString());
  }
}}
```

This way the logic will be executed only if the user is selecting something and not on other primary events that might set off the secondary select event (focus, keypress, etc).

Comment: This workaround is quite nice actually. Thanks a lot. And by the way, I just discovered that mouseUp and mouseDown events are not getting fired in React. Maybe you might know any fix for this problem too ?

Comment: @seymurium glad it works! In react you actually don't use `mouseUp` or `mouseDown` you would use `onMouseUp` and `onMouseDown`.

Comment: Sorry, I actually meant onMouseUp and onMouseDown. They're not getting fired for some reason

Comment: @seymurium Would you happen to have another question/code example on stack for it? There are a number of reasons why they might be buggy but I don't see any use of them in the code for this question

Comment: Man, don't know how, but now somehow they started working, lol :D Thanks for the discussion !

Comment: @seymurium haha happens sometimes. No problem at all!